# Re-use the context menu from explorer view in another tree view in VSCode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VSCode extension that adds a new file explorer view to the Explorer activity.

Is it possible to make my new view re-use the context menu (ie. right-click menu) from the file explorer view? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as discussed in this GitHub issue: [How to apply File Explorer context menu to custom tree view?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48932).

> There are no plans to support file explorer context menu items in custom tree view context menu.